# Get the last Date of Array to every category in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a Array with Customer Objects. They have an ID, category and a date. In the list it can happen that there are different dates for the same categories.

```
Customer 1 | qualityCheck | 12.03.2022
Customer 1 | priceCheck   | 05.07.2021
Customer 1 | customerCheck| 25.10.2022
Customer 1 | qualityCheck | 19.09.2020
Customer 1 | priceCheck   | 15.05.2022
```

Now i need for every Category the latest date. For the example above it would be like this.

```
Customer 1 | qualityCheck | 12.03.2022
Customer 1 | customerCheck| 25.10.2022
Customer 1 | priceCheck   | 15.05.2022
```

It can be that the list has 100 entries or also only 1. how can i solve this? it would be easiest if i had a new list with this items

Comment: Don't add unrelated tags to your question. Your question has nothing to do with vue.js or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

sort your array then get last obj for each category

```
let sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => {
return a.cat.localeCompare(b.cat) || new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)})


let result = []
for(let i = 0 ; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        let existed = result.find(eel => eel.cat === sorted[i].cat )
    if(!existed) {
    result.push(sorted[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easy ways would be to sort your list first by date, and then group.

```
   Map<String, Optional<Customer>> result = list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Customer::getDate))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Customer::getCategory,
            LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Customer::getDate))));
```

You can then use this map to retrieve your data:

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, Optional<Customer>> entry : result.entrySet()) 
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() +
                       ", Value = " + entry.getValue().get().getDate());
```